# I can't get c# method name by func<T1,T2>

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetFuncName<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> func){
    return func.Method.Name;
}
```

I use this code can get "`string function(string)`" structure method name.

But I can't get "`void function()`" structure method name.

> "GetFuncName(xxx)" throws volid error.

I need get the "`void function()`" name finally.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If you need call function such as: var demo = GetFuncName(new Func<Country, string>(x => x.CountryName));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a void you will need an `Action<>` type delegate and not a Func delegate.

So you will need another method

```
public static string GetActionName<T1>(Action<T1> action){
    return action.Method.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I need to find the intrudoction. It works good.  Now I can use "CancelInvoke (GetFuncName(actionCancelShaking));" and "Invoke (GetFuncName(actionCancelShaking), .05f);" instead function name. Strong code.

Comment: I define two "public static string GetFuncName<T1>(Action<T1> action)" and "public static string GetFuncName(Action action)"

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the method name via `Delegate.Method.Name`. IMO your method is not necessary to be generic.

```
public static string GetDelegateName(Delegate instance)
{
    return instance.Method.Name;
}
```